# Bool: Incorrect output of cout not 0 or 1

Tags: c++, boolean, cout

I have a function that reads in requests: by timestamp, current floor, and destination floor and it is not outputting the way I expected.

All my member values are outputting correctly : timestamp, current floor, and destination floor except for the bool.

The bool outputs 205 instead 1 or 0 for my direction.

```
Elevator::readRequests()

{
  ifstream myStream("T1.txt");

while(!myStream.eof())
{
    int timestamp ,currentFloor, destinationFloor;


    myStream >> timestamp >> currentFloor >> destinationFloor;
    //cout<< endl <<"The current timestamp is "<< timestamp << "The current floor is " << currentFloor 
    //  << " and the destination floor is " << destinationFloor << endl << endl;
    //cout<< endl;

    reqNode *temp = new reqNode;

    //initialize request node object
    temp->timestamp = timestamp;
    temp->start = currentFloor;
    temp->destination = destinationFloor;
    temp->start_time = -1;
    temp->finish_time = -1;

    temp->calculate_priority();

    if(temp->start < temp->destination)
        temp->set_dir(true);
    else
        temp->set_dir(false);

    request.push(*temp);//push nodes into the request bank
}
int i = 0;
while( !request.empty() )
{

    cout << "Node " << i << " : " << request.front().timestamp << " " <<    request.front().start << " " << request.front().destination
        << " " <<  request.front().direction << endl;

    request.pop();//popping the request in order to test
    i++;
}


}
```

I am trying to get the output:

Node # : Timestamp. Current(User Floor). Destination(User Floor). Direction(User is heading).

```
Node 0 : 1 3 7 1
Node 1 : 1 2 9 1
Node 2 : 1 7 9 1
Node 3 : 2 4 6 1
Node 4 : 2 4 8 1
Node 5 : 2 1 17 1
Node 6 : 5 1 15 1
Node 7 : 5 5 1 0
Node 8 : 6 17 4 0
Node 9 : 6 4 17 1
```

Instead I am getting as output:

```
Node 0 : 1 3 7 205
Node 1 : 1 2 9 205
Node 2 : 1 7 9 205
Node 3 : 2 4 6 205
Node 4 : 2 4 8 205
Node 5 : 2 1 17 205 
Node 6 : 5 1 15 205
Node 7 : 5 5 1 205
Node 8 : 6 17 4 205
Node 9 : 6 4 17 205
```

this is the file T1.txt:

```
1 3 7
1 2 9
1 7 9
2 4 6
2 4 8
2 1 17
5 1 15
5 5 1
6 17 4
6 4 17
```

Comment: Please show the code for `reqNode`.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see a `bool` in there anywhere..

Answer (score 3):

`205` is `0xCD`. That usually means that you are using an uninitialized variable.

Based on the code in the original question, you need to copy `direction` in the copy constructor of `reqNode`. Based on the output, it was not copied.

Also, since your vector appears to be `vector<reqNode>`, you don't need to allocate the temporary `reqNode` with `new`. Just create it on the stack and pass that to `requests.push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

`request.push(*temp)` makes a copy of the object that `temp` points to. As a matter of style, you should delete the pointer after doing this, since that object is no longer needed. Even better, create it as an auto object instead of newing it. C++ isn't Java.

Since the copy that's getting stored has different values from the original, it suggests that the copy constructor for `reqNode` isn't copying correctly.